# openal pitch shift

Tags: audio, volume, openal, pitch

Can anyone tell me why the volume becomes lower when I make the pitch higher in openal? The higher the pitch, the lower the volume.....

alSourcef(source, AL_PITCH, 1.2f);
 alSourcef(source, AL_GAIN, 1.0f);

with this setting, the volume is still very very low. is there a way to cheat it to make the gain above 1? Maybe this has something to do with distance??

FYI, the source is a voice recorded from AVrecorder, so I cant set the source volume any higher.

Comment: I assume you're talking about perceived loudness vs. some sort of observed change in amplitude...? What sort of sample are you playing? You may be dropping frequencies or exceeding the capabilities of your hardware to render them (or your ears to perceive them...)

Comment: alSourcef(source, AL_PITCH, 1.2f);
 alSourcef(source, AL_GAIN, 1.0f);

Comment: just a tiny bit change in the pitch....

Comment: Higher frequency sustained sounds will be perceived by the human ear to be "quieter" than a lower frequency sound of identical amplitude. Higher frequency short sounds (less than a quarter second) will be perceived by the human ear to be "louder" than a lower frequency sound of identical amplitude.

Answer (score 3):

Afaik it is not normal that the amplitude would change in function of pitch change. When pitch is set higher than original, openal speeds up the sample by the multiplier (afaik) using some sort of interpolation when the multiplier is not whole.

There might be some rare cases where the amplitude changes, but probably not for longer samples with lots of frequency content (as most natural sounds tend to be)

How loud we perceive that amplitude depends on the pitch, see [equal loudness contour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal-loudness_contour)
Maybe that effect explains your question?

As workaround you could lower the gain for normal pitched sounds and use higher gain for higher pitched sounds.
Or multiply the source data by a multiplier before attaching/passing to a buffer.

Comment: ah, I like the multiplier idea for the source data. I will look into that. Thanks Emile :)

Comment: Thank you everybody for the help, I found setting the gain way higher than 1, such as 5, or 100 solved the low volume problem.  :)